# Type S Mortar suitable for basement bathtub install?

Tags: basement, bathtub, installation

I’m installing a Delta acrylic tub in the basement on concrete. I have a bag of Type S mortar from a different project.

Is that suitable for this installation? Delta’s instructions don’t have a specific type of mortar mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no, no, do not use Type S mortar for setting your acrylic tub/shower base…it mixes too wet and will shrink.

Here’s a link that explains why Type S is bad:

https://www.sakrete.com/blog/concrete-insider-concrete-interiors

I’ve got to downvote @r13 answer because it will cause cracking and leaks.

Comment: You are correct. +1

Comment: So then a Type N?